# Why is it slow or not working when accessing the website

Tags: web, server, web-testing

When an event is run on a website, the website is frequently down, which is down in two cases.
(1) Access is possible, but access is very slow.
(2) Access is not possible, so we can't access the website.

What is the difference between two cases? Is it the difference the remaining range of bandwidths between the website and the server?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not start checking your server's error log?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "bandwidths between the website and the server"?

Comment: Hi Nico, Thanks for your comments, it's not our problem, just curiosity, Bandwith is actually, i mean server's storage...